# Does WPF still leak on Custom ICommand implementations?

Tags: .net-4.5, icommand

Before .Net 4.5, WPF controls used to leak on custom `ICommand` implementations that did not use a weak event pattern because they did not unsubscribe from the `CanExecuteChanged` event of the interface.

We now have the `CanExecuteChangedEventManager` class and a quick JustDecompile search finds that clases like `MenuItem` and `ButtonBase` are using the manager, thus avoiding the leak.

Is there still the need to use a weak event pattern when creating a custom `ICommand`?